# Pivot Longer with separated prefix

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, data-cleaning

I have to make this dataframe **Increm_Moran** longer in order to make visualisations.

[image]

I have basically a common column distance, and then MoranIndex and zscore for 16 variables (community,csrstrategy, + 14 more)

I have tried to pivot longer with code below. Problem is
I can't have **Pillar** as a third column (essential because it will help differentiate observations), and  single column with value.

```
try1 <- Increm_Moran %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -Distance, 
    names_to = "Pillar",
    values_to = "Value")



try2 <- Increm_Moran %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -Distance,
    names_to = c(".value", "Pillar"),
    names_sep = "_", 
    values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

[image: First try]

[image: Second try]

The second try seems more relevant to me. Just two colomns are missing :

- one more column **value** with numerical data,
- another with the **name** of pillar (community, csrstrategy, etc).

| Value | Pillar |
| --- | --- |
| 12.1 | community |
| 12.34 | community |
| 43.43 | csrstrategy |
| 34.34 | csrstrategy |

Pivoting gives headaches really fast, if you have any advice, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer while writing this post.
I give the answer if this can help other people

```
    temp <- pivot_longer(Increm_Moran, -Distance, 
names_sep = "\\_", names_to = c("Pillar", "variable"))
```

and the output :

[image]